# How with Faker fill created_at field with relative date?

Tags: laravel, faker

I make dummy data with fzaninotto/Faker my Laravel 8  app
and for model ConversationMessage I need to fill created_at field with relative date from latest
date and first ID(say month ago) till now with biggest ID
I check method dateTimeBetween, but can I do as I need ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
'created_at'=>$this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-2 day' ),
```

or you can initialize the $date before return in the factory class

```
    public function definition()
    {
    $date = $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-1 day' );
        return [
        'created_at'=>$date,
        'updated_at'=>$date
        ];
    }
```

Take a look [Laracasts discus](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/factory-created-at)

Comment: No that does not work. $date in this casealays between 2021-07-30 and 2021-07-31. Somehow I need to keep value from prior definition metthod and add say 1 hour. I thought about sessions, but if sessions are supported in factory ?